# How to create async requests, blocker methods in ruby API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-2.0

I am Creating API in ruby.

Was looking into the async requests, blocker methods like wait for async operations..

Can anybody suggest which is the best way to handle Asynchronous operations for API

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus) gem which is built to run HTTP requests in parallel.

The idea is to prepare several requests with blocks for handling success/error for each request, then to run all of them in parallel. The "run phase" will block until all requests are completed.

Here's a sample from the project page:

```
hydra = Typhoeus::Hydra.hydra

first_request = Typhoeus::Request.new("http://example.com/posts/1")
first_request.on_complete do |response|
  third_url = response.body
  third_request = Typhoeus::Request.new(third_url)
  hydra.queue third_request
end
second_request = Typhoeus::Request.new("http://example.com/posts/2")

hydra.queue first_request
hydra.queue second_request
hydra.run # this is a blocking call that returns once all requests are complete
```

In the event you don't want to wait for your asynchronous operation to end (but your question suggests otherwise) then it's a bit more complicated: you should have an API to run the request and return a request ID to the caller, which could later query the API for a result associated with the request ID it received.

To be a bit more flexible, you could use [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday), a HTTP client lib that provides a uniform interface to several backends. Start with any backend you like, and you should be able to change the adapter to another one later on if you want to test/improve performance.

Typhoeus provides a Faraday backend, but you can also use [EM-HTTP-Request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request) which is based on [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine), a well-known gem. You can leverage Ruby's Fibers with Faraday and EM-Synchrony as shown [in this example](https://gist.github.com/igrigorik/802395).

Here's a sample running parallel requests with Faraday and Typhoeus: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/wiki/Parallel-requests

Using the previous example, it should be easy to adapt to use the EM-HTTP-request adapter.

Comment: Thanks @Olivier ...Ill try this ...Even i got one article on google https://www.igvita.com/2009/05/13/fibers-cooperative-scheduling-in-ruby/ ... which one is good could you suggest me.

Comment: I guess Typhoeus is a good bet, probably better than handling Fibers yourself anyway... I'll update my answer with alternatives :)

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer solves your problem, don't forget to accept it ^^